# Would the Netherlands refuse entry for a Schengen visa issued by the Italian embassy?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, italy, netherlands

I have a valid multiple-entry Schengen visa issued by the Italian embassy in Thailand. I have a Thai passport. The visa is issued for 2 years. I am planning a trip to the Netherlands in the upcoming months, but I will not be planning on going to Italy.

I heard some people saying that the Netherlands may refuse entry as a first destination (first port of entry since it should be to Italy). (This won't be my first time entering the Schengen area with my Italian visa. Will they refuse my entry? If so, what can I do to prevent that?

Side note: I recently visited the Netherlands with my Italian visa and it was my first time entering the Schengen area since I got my visa and I almost did not get in, but was still let in. Would that be on my record?

Comment: Some people say nonsense in many cases.  Schengen rules actually *require* travelers to get their visa from a country other than their first port of entry for certain itineraries.

Answer (score 7):

I think what "some people" say is a garbled account of the rules.

- When you have a **single-entry** visa, the trip should be in accordance with your application. If you have a tourist visa for Greece and you show up in Finland, there will be questions.
- Even with a **single-entry** visa, you can make minor changes. If you planned a holiday in Greece with a flight via Paris (i.e. entering the Schengen area in France) and you change the itinerary to a flight via Amsterdam (i.e. entering the Schengen area in the Netherlands) that would be allowed. Note that for either case you would need a Greek visa if the main destination is Greece.
- You may not misrepresent your itinerary in the hopes that this makes the visa easier (and usually it doesn't, anyway). When you are changing your itinerary, it is a good idea to avoid the *appearance* that you lied about it.

---

- When you have a **multiple-entry** visa, the first trip should be in accordance with your application, just like the first (and only) trip with a single-entry visa.
- Subsequent trips on a **multiple-entry** visa can be to any Schengen state.
- On arrival, you should be prepared to explain the itinerary of your trip, have enough money for subsistence in the Schengen area, health insurance, etc.